# SSSD list allowed users only

Tags: authentication, active-directory, sssd

With nscd/nslcd authentication scheme, it was possible to get a list of allowed users issuing this command: `getent passwd`

How can this be achieved with SSSD? There is an option enumeration,
but this lists all users.

I am only interested in the allowed users. I filter them with:

```
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = Computer Admins
```

Using: sssd 1.12.5-1~trusty1

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I am also interested in this. thanks.

Comment: No, I use this method now: `cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf | grep simple` then I pick a group to run `getent group allow-access-group`

Answer (score 1):

Tell [`getent`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html#OPTIONS) what service you want to query, like this:

```
getent -s files passwd
getent -s sss   passwd
getent          passwd
```

The last line merges the "files" and "sss" entries.  The "files" entries are from `/etc/passwd`.

The "sss" entries are from the SSSD service.  However, for this to work, you must have **"enumerate = true"** in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`, and of course the SSSD service has to be working.